# How to add constrains to storyboard for IBDesignable custom UI

Tags: ios, uibutton, custom-controls, ibdesignable

I've created IBDesignable custom UIButton, this is my button:

[image]

and then I add constraints to it:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
let leftConstrain = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)
let rightConstrain = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8)
let bottomConstrain = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8)
let height = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leftConstrain, rightConstrain, bottomConstrain, height])
```

after I add constraints it goes to be something like this:

[image]

The problem is the frame of the button, the view height and position was changed, but the frame doesn't change and there are no constraints.

How can I force the frame to be compatible with the constraints I added?

Comment: What actually you wanted to achieve?

Comment: I want to change height button (and if it can possible, add some constraints), and it should be applied to the effect too. I tried several times, the button has been changed, but the frame of the button not! as I mentioned in pictures. @dahiya_boy

Comment: if you wanted to change the hieght then change the height constant from 60 to other constant that you wanted.

Comment: @dahiya_boy did you see the pictures?please see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bypHx.png, I changed the height of button, but the frame doesn't change. see the image please to figure out what I say.

Comment: Is your view class just a subclass of UIButton or is the button a subview of your custom class?

Comment: @Paulw11 it is a subclass of UIButton.

Comment: @SadraIsapanahAmlashi if your frame is doesn't change then what is the that button which is wide and grey in color at the bottom of pink view.??

Comment: @dahiya_boy I mean the selectable frame, the item in the center that has the border and I can select it. the center one, that's the frame holder. there is no change in it.
I want to be this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bypHx.png
but it is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bypHx.png

Comment: Why are you adding constraints programmatically between your button and the superview?  You should add those constraints in interface builder. You could add the height constraint if you wanted, I guess

Comment: let me explain it to you @Paulw11. I want to make a reusable button for design system, and it has to be with a fixed height. I added constraints and height truly, the button view has been changed, but the frame of the button not! and want to change the size of button view and selectable frame together like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bypHx.png, but the result is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bypHx.png :(((

Comment: As I said, it can add the height constraint programmatically , but the leading/trailing/bottom constraints should be added through Interface Builder.